# slow query performance, between identical version on database server

Tags: mysql, performance

my problem is :

That I have a query who taking more time on one mysql server, than another mysql server. The query taking more time on the server that is better dimmensioned than the other one.
The query is alerady well optimised.

explain :

[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd6br.png)

Details:
same characteristics on both servers :

- database server version : mariadb 10.1.47
- query plan execution : same
- table structure of query : same
- number rows returned: 79
- parameters in my.cnf : exactly the same on both.
- mysql default parameters allocation : default madriadb installation allocation
- charactere_set :  UTF8 on both (table, database,server, tomcat)
- storage engine : INNODB

characteristics that are differents between two servers :

test server :

- memory : 79M
- query time execution : 2,5 sc

Prod server :

- memory : 31,4G
- query time execution : 10,00sc

My question is, why the query taking more time on the prod server ? I don't have any idea at this time ...

thanks for help

Comment: I'm not think that configuration optimized for test server with 80M memory will be optimal for prod server with 32G RAM. You should to tune each MySQL server installation

Comment: Other than the obvious of there being more server activity on a production server, or the servers actually being different, can you post the execution plan? There might be a hint in there. Your server could not be using, or wrongfully using, said optimisations.

Comment: the prod server is a new server, there are no clients for the moment, we test the database before to put it online.

Comment: 79M???  Is the Query cache turned off?  (It should be off.)  Did you time each machine twice (to eliminate differences in I/O caching)?  Is either machine swapping?